# How to create array of JSON objects with multiple values?

Tags: python, append

I tried using an append to create a new array. However, either the created function returns an array with several objects and not an object with several values.

Code->

```
def parse_json(self, data):
    file = 'vault.json'
    json = {}
    for obj in data:
        if 'EMAIL' in obj[0]:
            json.setdefault('EMAIL', []).append({obj[0]: obj[1]})
        if 'TEST' in obj[0]:
            json.setdefault('TEST', []).append({obj[0]: obj[1]})
        else:
            json.setdefault('VAULT', []).append({obj[0]: obj[1]})

    with open(file, 'w') as f:
        dump(json, f, indent=2, separators=(',', ':'))
```

Response ->

```
{
  "EMAIL":[
     {"EMAIL_CC":""},
     {"EMAIL_CCO":""},
     {"EMAIL_DESTINY":"teste@gmail.com"}
   ]
}
```

Desired answer ->

```
{
  "EMAIL":{
    "EMAIL_CC":"",
    "EMAIL_CCO":"",
    "EMAIL_DESTINY":"teste@gmail.com"
  }
}
```

Comment: You should [edit] your question and add a sample of the data being parsed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In python, the curly brackets { } are used for dictionaries, which are similar to javascript objects (which sounds like what you're familiar with). The hard brackets [ ] are called lists. Your desired response looks like a dictionary with a key that has a dictionary as its value. Unfortunately, you can't add key-value pairs into a list or array in python, so you should instead make another dictionary instead of a list or rethink what your desired list would look like (perhaps only the values and not the keys).

TL;DR: you are appending dictionaries to your list:
`.append({obj[0]: obj[1]})` 
`{obj[0]: obj[1]}` is a dictionary you are appending to the list.
In python you can have a list of dictionaries but you cant have just key-value pairs in a list

Answer (score 0):

Use [dictionaries](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_dictionaries.asp).

It seems that when you add to your json, you add the data as list instead of dictionary.

Also, I'd like to note that you generally shouldn't use `setdefault` in this situation. You should instead just directly add keys to your dictionary, since it is already empty. So instead of `json.setdefault('EMAIL', []).append({obj[0]: obj[1]})`, you could just use `json[obj[0]] = obj[1]`

Comment: Got it, but how could I name the array index?

Example:
{
     "INDEX": {
         "EMAIL_CC": "",
         "EMAIL_CCO": "TEST@GMAIL.COM"
     },
     "INDEX": {
         "TEST": "123",
         "TEST2": "1234"
     }
}

Comment: If I understand right, you mean key not index. But naming it is simple: `my_dictionary[key] = value`,  where key is the index.

Answer (score 0):

JSON objects correspond to Python dictionaries, and JSON arrays to Python lists—see the `json` module's [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#encoders-and-decoders)—so what you're trying to create is a dictionary of dictionaries based on what you indicated is the desired answer (not a dictionary of lists). That's why creating lists and appending to them isn't appropriate.

You haven't provided any sample of the input `data`, and you've also left out a number of other details, so I had to make some guesses, but hopefully what's shown in the code below similar enough for you to see how it apply it.

```
import json

class Class:
    def parse_json(self, data):
        categories = ('EMAIL', 'TEST')
        file = 'vault.json'
        json_obj = {}

        for obj in data:
            for group in categories:
                if group in obj[0]:
                    category = json_obj.setdefault(group, {})
                    break
            else:
                category = json_obj.setdefault('VAULT', {})

            category[obj[0]] = obj[1]

        with open(file, 'w') as f:
            json.dump(json_obj, f, indent=2, separators=(',', ':'))


data = [
    ["EMAIL_CC", ""],
    ["EMAIL_CCO", ""],
    ["EMAIL_DESTINY", "teste@gmail.com"],
    ["TEST_CC", ""],
    ["TEST_KARMA", "testf@gmail.com"],
    ["OTHER_CC", ""],
    ["SOMETHING_CC2", ""],
    ["FOOBAR_BAZ", "testg@gmail.com"],
]

cls = Class()
cls.parse_json(data)
print('-fini-')
```

Contents of the `vault.json` file that's created:

```
{
  "EMAIL":{
    "EMAIL_CC":"",
    "EMAIL_CCO":"",
    "EMAIL_DESTINY":"teste@gmail.com"
  },
  "TEST":{
    "TEST_CC":"",
    "TEST_KARMA":"testf@gmail.com"
  },
  "VAULT":{
    "OTHER_CC":"",
    "SOMETHING_CC2":"",
    "FOOBAR_BAZ":"testg@gmail.com"
  }
}
```